# Using an IF statement to displays views

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I am create an iOS app where I need to display a different view depending on the result from an API call. At the momment I am querying the database, saving the result and then using this result to form an IF statement where I load up the correct view like so

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(180.0f, 24.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
JHView *myView = [[JHFewCloudsView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self.view myView];
```

Although this works it seems slow and like a lot of code for a simple task. Is there a better way to have multiple views? Can you use many `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` in one view and just call the relevant one that you need?

```
    if ([icon  isEqual: @"01d"])
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(180.0f, 24.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
        JHSunView *sunView = [[JHSunView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        [self.view addSubview:sunView];

    } else if ([icon isEqualToString:@"02d"])
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(180.0f, 24.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
        JHFewCloudsView *fewCloudsView = [[JHFewCloudsView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        [self.view addSubview:fewCloudsView];
    }
```

The way I am doing it now means I will end up with 15 different views and very messy code.

Comment: "`[self.view myView];`" does not look correct to me.  "`self.view = myView`" is probably what you meant?

Comment: Show the `if` code. You might want to use a lookup table. But your actual issue isn't 100% clear currently...

Comment: See update @Wain and nope [self.view myView] is correct

Answer (score 0):

If your code is as repetitive as shown in the question (the only difference is the class name) then you can create a dictionary where the keys are the strings in your `if` statements and the values are the names of the classes (as strings). Then your code becomes:

```
Class viewClass = NSClassFromString([self.viewConfig objectForKey:icon]);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(180.0f, 24.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
UIView *newView = [[[viewClass alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self.view addSubview: newView];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, each class is represented by an object (of type `Class`) that you can treat just like other objects.  In particular, you can use a `Class` as the value in a dictionary, store it in a variable, and send it messages.  Thus:

```
static NSDictionary *viewClassForIconName(NSString *iconName) {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static NSDictionary *dictionary;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        dictionary = @{
            @"01d": [JHSunView class],
            @"02d": [JHFewCloudsView class],
            // etc.
        };
    });
    return dictionary;
}

- (void)setViewForIconName:(NSString *)iconName {
    Class viewClass = viewClassForIconName(iconName);
    if (viewClass == nil) {
        // unknown icon name
        // handle error here
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(180.0f, 24.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
    UIView *view = [[viewClass alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```